# C# Derive a class as array

Tags: c#, oop

I couldn't find my question here so I just ask, hope it is a new question.

Suppose I have a base class named **Base** and there is a function in **Base** named **Reset**, I am going to define array of **Base** class but every time I want to reset all array items I have to iterate all elements **Reset** function.

My question is : Is there a way I derive the **Base** class as **Child** class which consists of array of **Base** and create a **ResetAll** function in **Child** to iterate all **Reset** functions of the array?

Or maybe create a **ResetAll** function which will trigger all **Reset** functions?

Comment: Well ResetAll() should be apart of array of list class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a derived class. Basically you do not want to iterate thru all the Base objects in the array and call Reset method on them whenever you want to Reset them all.

All you need is an extension method for the Array of Base.

You can read about extension methods at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

For your case, you can create extension method as following.

```
public static class BaseExtensions
{
    public static void ResetAll(this Base[] baseArray)
    {
        foreach(var baseItem in baseArray)
        {
            baseItem.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use above method as following.

```
//Let say you have a an array of base as following.
Base[] items = new Base[2];
items[0] = new Base();
items[1] = new Base(); 

//You can reset them as following.
items.ResetAll(); //This is the ResetAll extension method created above.
```

This should help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: The keyword `this` might be useful when defining an extension method. ;-)

Comment: Good catch by @Enigmativity. and dumb mistake by me.... Thank you for pointing out. I corrected the mistake.